# Unable to access my plugins

Tags: wp-admin

What does this mean when I try to access my plugins in the admin?

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home/xyz/public_html/abc/tuv/wp-includes/kses.php(1005) : runtime-created function on line 1

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your wp-config.php file:
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

OR

If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
If your line shows 32M try 64M:
memory_limit = 64M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)